# Receiving MaximumListenersPerEndpoint:25 or System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException for service bus relay

Tags: servicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I am using a service bus relay and are receiving the following error

There is only one application connecting to the path, and for some reason the number of listeners has climbed to 25, but there is not 25 listeners.

During testing I am ending the program and likely not calling "close" on the end point, but I would have through that service bus would clean this up.  At any point in time there would only be one active listener on the end-point/path

I am not aware of a way of removing these end points, is there a way of clearing old dead listeners from a service bus?  This now means my service cannot run or connect, and I can't find a way to fix the issue.

[ServiceBus Relay Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBNLQ.png)

System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException occurred
   HResult=-2146233087
   Message=MaximumListenersPerEndpoint:25. TrackingId:d79456b4-cf41-4d4e-aa0a-88ccc6b82417_G12,TimeStamp:6/11/2015 4:42:29 AM
   Source=Microsoft.ServiceBus
   StackTrace:
        at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayListener.RelayedOnewayAmqpListenerClient.AmqpRelayedConnection.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
        at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayListener.RelayedOnewayAmqpListenerClient.GetOrCreateConnection(Uri via, TimeSpan timeout)
        at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayListener.RelayedOnewayAmqpListenerClient.Connect(TimeSpan timeout)
        at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayTcpClient.EnsureConnected(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean isRetry)
        at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayTcpClient.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
        at Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)..........................

Answer (score 0):

If the endpoint is persistent, you can delete the endpoint and recreate it. I am not sure how long it will take for the listeners to become deregistered, but deleting the endpoint should automatically remove them.